# Adding Query String with action link in PHP

Tags: php, html, query-string

How to add query string in php at the end of action link

`<form name="addtocart" action="../resources/scripts/addtocart.php?id='".$row['id']."'"  method="post">`

Comment: What's the problem with this code? Excluding `'`s which are useless.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in HTML context :

```
<form name="addtocart" 
      action="../resources/scripts/addtocart.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"  
      method="post">
```

If you are in PHP context with single quotes :

```
echo '<form name="addtocart" 
            action="../resources/scripts/addtocart.php?id='.$row['id'].'"  
            method="post">' ;
```

If you are in PHP context with double quotes :

```
echo "<form name=\"addtocart\" 
            action=\"../resources/scripts/addtocart.php?id=".$row['id']."\"  
            method=\"post\">" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put it in the action URL, place a hidden tag within the form and submit it with the request. This way you can just use `$_POST` on the server-side because you have `method="post"`.

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'">';
```